# Are the ads still being shown?

Tags: support, advertising

I don't see any more ads on the site. I'm not sure if it is something to do with Firefox 10.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're still there.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be Firefox or Addblock, not sure. They are showing in Chromium though. Thanks!

Comment: Adblock Plus blocks them.